# Android/Koin - How to tell koin that a single dependency should be reinitialized

Tags: android, dependency-injection, retrofit2, koin

I stumbled across a problem where I have to reinitialize my Retrofit API class because the URL changes, so I want to tell Koin to reinitialize the single dependency. I don't want to use factory because it is still a singleton most of the time.

Stopping and starting koin would be an idea but that is a very heavy and time intense prozess so I don't want to do that.

any ideas?

Comment: why don't you create 2 instances with 2 different base urls?

Comment: The problem is that this case can happen more often then 2 times so I would need to create a new retrofit instance every time I use it. SO I thought about solving it in koin, to recreate only one single dependency

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After doing A LOT OF RESEARCH, I found this post on [GitHub](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/676) scoping is the solution for my problem.

--- **OR** ---

using

```
unloadKoinModules(networkModule)
loadKoinModules(networkModule)
```

and then get the instance again:

```
val api: InstanceApi = getKoin().get()
```

Comment: But the isuue author wrote about a leak. Do you consider that?

Comment: I just mentioned the issue because it is providing the solution. It is not the same issue I had. Never had problems with the solution here.

Comment: loadKoinModules not loading latest modules